# JavaのSocket通信について

Tags: java, socket

JavaのSocket通信について質問です。
以下のソースがあったとして、
このソースでは`res.write(request);`でリクエストを送信後、
`res.flush();`でフラッシュしています。
この後、レスポンスを受信する処理が続きます。
リクエストを送信して何も応答がなかった場合、どうなるのでしょうか？
処理が止まってしまうのでしょうか？
またはExceptionが発生してしまうのでしょうか？

```
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
res = new PrintWriter(writer);
requ = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

// リクエスト送信
res.write(request);
res.flush();

// レスポンス受信
SocketResponse response = req.parseResponse(requ);
```

Comment: 一般的な話ではなくこのソースでの回答が知りたいということでしょうか？その場合req.parseResponse()の実装次第なのですが、reqはどういったクラスのインスタンスでしょうか？またrequ, req, requestが混在していてわかりづらくなっています。質問文を修正していただけますか。

Comment: マルチポスト　http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q12169732012

Answer (score 1):

応答がなかった時にプログラムが止まってしまわないように、socketにsetSoTimeoutメソッドを使ってタイムアウト時間を設定します。

```
socket.setSoTimeout(2000);
```

というような感じで。（タイムアウト時間はミリ秒単位で指定しますので、上の例では2秒以内に受信できなかったらSocketTimeoutExceptionが発生します）

Socketのタイムアウトのデフォールトは0(無限)になっているので、タイムアウト時間の設定を習慣にしたほうが"プログラムが止まってるみたいだけど、、、"というトラブルを減らせます。

Answer (score 0):

SocketTimeoutExceptionが発生するのでは？
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/net/SocketTimeoutException.html